# What are these elements called?

Tags: grammar

> Desert oases are the main, **in many cases the only**, source of water in the region. 
>   Tommy, **along with the other students**, breathed a sigh of relief.

Sometimes I see a phrase or even a clause in the middle of a sentence and is set apart from the rest with commas. What are these element called ?

Comment: These elements seem to be called *interrupters*.

Comment: Each is a *parenthesis*, plural *parentheses*. The usual name in the US for the punctuation marks () derives from this term.

Comment: Thanks. But how to differentiate them from those conjunctive adverbs like :**however,on the other hand,** or they are somewhat similar? I mean, in some way in add "something" to the sentence which's very much like adverbs(adverbials)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Guide to Grammar and Writing](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/commas.htm), they are called *parenthetical elements* or *added information*. To set off these elements, we use two commas. It simply means that the part of sentence is set off with two commas is there to give us *additional information* removing which would not affect the meaning of the sentence.

> Use a comma to set off parenthetical elements, as in "The Founders Bridge, **which spans the Connecticut River**, is falling down."
>
> By "parenthetical element," we mean a part of a sentence that can be removed without changing the essential meaning of that sentence. The parenthetical element is sometimes called "added information."

---

*But how to differentiate them from those conjunctive adverbs like :**however,on the other hand,** or they are somewhat similar?*

*However, Nevertheless...* etc. talk about the other aspect of the matter said earlier *(-say "I like you, however, I cannot marry you")*. They have no connection with parenthetical elements because the latter ones are additional information, and the clauses you put after what you call adverbs are essential parts of the sentence.